# Asynchronous functions inside for loop Wait for the loop to complete then perform the next action

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying loop through a list of Reddit links and download them one by one.

I have an async function that retrieves imgur album images , and downloads them

```
async function getAlbum(sub,title,id,psub,auth) {

   let p = {}
   let alburls  = []
   let result = await   getAlbumImages(id)

   let re = result.data.data.images

   for(v of re)
   {
    var ext = v.link.split('.').pop();
    if(psub == true) {
      file_name = title + ' '+ 'U-- ' +auth+ '.'+ext
    } else {
      file_name = title+ '.' +ext
    }
      await downloadFile( v.link,file_name)
   }
    console.log({re});

}
```

this method downloads the retrieved file

```
var downloadFile =  async (link,filename) => {

  request
    .get(link)
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
    .pipe(writeFile(filename,dir))
    .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + filename);

      });
 }
```

Both functions work fine, but the issue here is the order of execution.

Shouldn't the   console.log({re}) in the first function come **after** the console.log in the downloadFile function? I'm getting the reverse. 
I want to execute a function AFTER the for loop is done it's work

Comment: You can consider using promise

Comment: You have declared `downloadFile` as an `async` function, but are not awaiting within the function. Also looks like you're mixing async/await, promises and callbacks all in your implementation

Comment: @Bosco where do you suggest I use promise?

Comment: What request library are you using? It will be easier if you use one that returns a promise.

Comment: @DanD I'm still trying to learn asynchronous and promises. I'm getting the same results even when downloadFile isn't declared as async

Comment: Use promise to wait for file download. Retrieving the file name is pretty faster. But downloading is not

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm just using request. Doesn't axios return promises?

Comment: @Sai, yes, all axios methods return promises. I think there is a fork for request with promises support, and of course, you can use fetch in the browser (or node-fech in the server-side). And if you use an API that returns promises, you don't need to mark the function as `async`.

Comment: @Sai, also consider if you really need to load the files sequentially. Since the requests are independent, they could be triggered concurrently. You can await all the results (using Promise.all).

Comment: @CMS it is very important that I load the files sequentially.

Comment: @Sai, if you use Promise.all, the order of the results will be in the order the promises are in the array you pass to the method. Check this simple example of loading three files concurrently, while getting the file contents in the right order: https://codesandbox.io/s/promiseall-72cr3

Comment: To make on point that is inherent in several comments super clear, your `downloadFile` function does not have a return statement.  When the body of your "fat arrow" function is enclosed in curly brackets you have to explicitly call return. In this case, because all async functions return a promise until resolved, I believe the function returns a resolved promise with the value `null` and immediately continue execution.  So if you switch to Axios or something to return a promise, make sure you put `return` in front so the promise is returned (or get rid of the curly brackets).

Comment: @HenryMueller, exactly!  The absence of the explicit return statement will simply produce a resolved promise to the value `undefined`. I'll add that if he is returning directly a promise without awaiting it (e.g. by using axios) the function doesn't need to be marked as async.

Comment: @CMS Thank you. I will consider using Promise.all in the future.

Comment: @HenryMueller  "When the body of your "fat arrow" function is enclosed in curly brackets you have to explicitly call return" I did not know that. Thank you. I'm still learning

Answer (score 2):

Your downloadFile function returns a promise that is immediately resolved as it does not await any asynchronous action. This could be solved by using a request library that returns promises but I am assuming that you are using one that does not.

You can wrap that request in a promise that resolves the promise in the callback. This is called "Promisifying" a callback.

```js
async function getAlbum(sub,title,id,psub,auth) {

   let p = {}
   let alburls  = []
   let result = await   getAlbumImages(id)

   let re = [{}

   for(v of re)
   {
    var ext = v.link.split('.').pop();
    if(psub == true) {
      file_name = title + ' '+ 'U-- ' +auth+ '.'+ext
    } else {
      file_name = title+ '.' +ext
    }
      await downloadFile( v.link,file_name)
   }
    console.log({re});

}

var downloadFile =  async (link,filename) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
      .get(link)
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        reject()
      })
      .pipe(writeFile(filename,dir))
      .on('finish', () => {
            console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + filename);
            resolve()
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not a worry. I've just read your comments on the question and it appears that you are using Axios which already returns promises. Can I suggest that you get away from using callbacks? I might publish an edit if you want it.

Comment: I'm not using Axios. Please post your suggestion

Comment: Ah ok. If that is the case then you are stuck with callbacks until nodejs gets all of its promisified core modules out of experimental mode.